# Octave/MATLAB: Variable Scopes and Name Lookup?

Tags: matlab, octave

So I have a cell array of vectors X:

```
octave:149> X
X = 
{
  [1,1] =

      1   17   20

  [2,1] =

      5   20   22   27

  [3,1] =

      2   17   18   21

}
```

I create an empty vector Y:

```
octave:150> Y = []
Y = [](0x0)
```

I then call an anonymous function on each value of X with "Y = unique([Y x])":

```
octave:151> cellfun(@(x)(Y = unique([Y x])),X,'UniformOutput',false)
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =

      1   17   20

  [2,1] =

      1    5   17   20   22   27

  [3,1] =

      1    2    5   17   18   20   21   22   27

}
```

Ok, but now Y is still empty:

```
octave:152> Y
Y = [](0x0)
octave:153>
```

Clearly the Y name inside the anonymous function created and bound a new storage for its own version of Y.

What are the storage and name resolution rules in Octave/MATLAB?  When is storage allocated for a variable?  When are two identical names bound to the same variable?  (Is there any way to effect the value of Y in the above anonymous function?)

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab functions have their own scope.  When you pass a variable, unless that variable is also in the output list, it will not be modified by the called function; the function makes a copy of the variable and the copy is what the function modifies.

With anonymous functions the variable is copied at function declaration.  See [this Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html).  This is what you are seeing with Y.

Also, I think that you are using cellfun incorrectly.  You should not return the value of the anonymous function inside the call to cellfun, but as a result of cellfun.

So, perhaps this is closer to what you want:

```
octave:151> Y = cellfun(@(x, y)(unique([y x])),X,Y,'UniformOutput',false)
```

I can't tell if you want the result of each call to the anonymous function to change Y and use that result in the next call.  If that is what you want, it will be more difficult.

Comment: I am trying to "union" accumulate the vectors in the cell array.  At the end Y should equal `[1    2    5   17   18   20   21   22   27]`

Comment: That is to say, I want to get the set union of the vectors in the cell array.

Comment: If the set union without intermediate steps is all you need, you can use the following: `Y = unique([X{:}])`. This uses the fact that Matlab can create arrays from [comma-seperated lists](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html#br2js35-9). This solution assumes that all the vectors inside the cell are `1xn`.